# Can't wrap the contents of ag-grid Row

Tags: html, css, angular, ag-grid-angular

I'm trying to wrap contents of a row of ag-grid into multiple lines but I can't get the contents to display over multiple lines. The data for rows is provided dynamically at the time of certain condition check.
I have tried using the `white-space:normal` property but it didn't do anything.
I also tried `wrap-text` but it is not a valid property.
Here's my code for reference.

**component.ts**

```
columnDefs = [
    {headerName: 'S.No.', field : 'SNo'},
    {headerName: 'Error Description', field: 'Error_Description', autoHeight: true},
]
rowData = []
```

**provide data to rows**

```
for(let i = 0; i<this.validationErrors.length;i++){
    let errorObj={};
    errorObj["SNo"]=i+1;
    errorObj["Error_Description"]=this.validationErrors[i];
    this.rowData=[...this.rowData, errorObj]
}
```

And here is a snapshot of the display

**index.html**
[image]

As you can see in the image, the `AZAAAAAA....` part is overflowing. The following is the css that is applied to the cell implicitly.

**style.css**

```
.ag-cell {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    text-overflow: initial;
    white-space: inherit;
}
```

If I try to alter the `text-overflow` property to `initial` or if I try to change the `white-space` to `normal`, it clips the entire `AZAAA...` part. 
How do I resolve this?

**Note:** I'm not using any of the APIs to handle rows or columns. I have just defined 2 arrays and bound them to the html as follows:

```
<ag-grid-angular [hidden]="isValid" class="ag-theme-balham" [rowData]="rowData" [columnDefs]="columnDefs">
<!-- Show table -->
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set 'width' param to the column.

Comment: you could leave this comment the post it self